# Custom auth provider - how to get a new access token without a refresh token

Tags: namedcredentials, auth-provider

I have to integrate Salesforce with an external app using OAuth2.0.
I create Auth. Provider and Named Credential, authenticated successfully too.

But I'm getting one issue with Named Credential :
`The authentication provider didn't provide a refresh token. If the access token expires, your org won't be able to access this named credential.`

With this issue I don't think the access token will be refreshed automatically, right?

What options do I have to get the access token once it expires?

I tried, `getAccessToken(authProviderId, providerName)` but it keeps returning null.
`String accessToken = Auth.AuthToken.getAccessToken('0SO5j000000sgZNGAY', 'Open ID Connect');`

Comment: You'd have to reinitialize the auth provider underneath NC to restart the token acquisition  sequence without the refresh token. One option: when token expires, manually delete NC and recreate it. (Do not delete  or touch Auth Provider).  There might be a less intrusive way to kick off a reinit...caveat emptor.

Comment: @identigral - The only downside is that currently Access_Token expires in 1 hour. But let's say if I get that extended to a week/month. Is it a good solution to initiate Authentication flow of Named Credential ever week/month in order to keep things running? Or should I build a custom apex code to fetch the access token itself?

Comment: Custom code is better.

Answer (score 2):

Got this resolved. Hope this helps someone.

The application exposing the REST API didn't had `offline_access` scope configured at their scope.

Once this is done, we need add the `offline_access` scope back to our NC and then Salesforce will be able to refresh the access token on its own.

Comment: Does this mean that named creds do not refresh tokens if there's nothing specified in the scope parameter ?